# How to get a substring of a URL in C#?

Tags: c#, string

This is my string:

```
<a href=\"https://vine.co/v/h7pUFJirEBX\" target=\"_blank\">https://t.co/LFIwdhvjB6</a>
```

The part that I want to retrieve is the one after "/v/" which is "h7pUFJirEBX".

Do you know of any way of doing it in C#?

Update: This is my code now.

```
        var findIndex = url.IndexOf("/v/");
        var stringTweet = url.Substring(findIndex + 3);
        var removeafter = stringTweet.IndexOf("\"");
        var finalString = stringTweet.Remove(removeafter);
        return finalString;
```

finalString is now "h7pUFJirEBX". This however, seems like an awful approach to the problem.

Comment: Please be more specific. Where do you get this string? And what exactly have you tried? Can you give us some code?

Comment: Have you tried a `Regex`?

Comment: @brianestey: Leave now before they see you.

Comment: Regex is a **bad idea** for urls, have you tried HTML Agility Pack?

Comment: Does it matter where it comes from? It comes from a feed(twitter). But yes, it may vary in length i guess.

Comment: @Sayse No i have not. Ill check it up

Answer (score 1):

[String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) is exact answer to question as asked. May even work for you:

```
 var result = "<a href=\"https://vine.co/v/h7pUFJirEBX\" target=\"_".Substring(24, 14);
```

Notes:

- parsing HTML with string manipulation (or even worse with Regular expressions) is hard. Please consider using HtmlAgilityPack
- manually splitting Urls is dangerous - please consider using [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class which gives you way to properly get components of a url like path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first extract the **href** attribute from there. You can use a `RegEx` or use the **agilitypack** to parse it for you: [Easily extracting links from a snippet of html with `HtmlAgilityPack`](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.pt/2009/11/easily-extracting-links-from-snippet-of.html)

From there you can:

```
var uri = new Uri(@"https://vine.co/v/h7pUFJirEBX\");

var yourValue = uri.AbsolutePath.Substring(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Find index of **"/v/"** sequence in your string using `IndexOf()`. Then take a `Substring()` starting found index to index of **"\"**. Not sure if its a good approach to parsing urls though.